# What is the idiomatic Rust way to deal with a lot of if-let-else code?

Tags: rust

I am trying to find out the current home directory of the user (toy project, learning Rust) and this is the code I am at currently:

```
let mut home_dir = if let Some(path) = env::home_dir() {
    if let Some(path_str) = path.to_str() {
        path_str.to_owned()
    } else {
        panic!("Found a home directory, but the encoding of the filename was invalid")
    }
} else {
    panic!("Could not find home directory for current user, specify prefix manually");
};
```

I come from a heavily managed-language background so maybe that is why this appears to me as a bit of an anti-pattern, but I am trying to understand if I there is a better way to do this.

In Kotlin I would deal with this situation using:

```
val homeDir = env.getHomeDir()?.toString() ?: throw RuntimeException(...)
```

The way the `?` macro works in Rust requires me to use a function that returns a `Result` which I believe `main()` does not, and it doesn't necessarily make sense anyways. Any pointers?

Comment: *use a function that returns a `Result`* — yes, so just make one ([example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7dc7332ec71906d7e84051e24d1c5dea&version=stable)). *I believe `main()` does not* — [not for long](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1937-ques-in-main.md)